# Postando no mural do grupo no facebook via php

Tags: php, facebook

Eu logo no facebook com meu perfil.
Uso wamp...
Tenho a seguinte variavel no meu *script* php

```
$texto = "Postando no grupo via php";
$grupo_id_url = "https://www.facebook.com/groups/617092775071175";
```

Quero que esta frase seja postada postada nesse grupo aí, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score -1):

O código está explicado, de uma olhada:
`

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'POST',
  '/{group-id}/feed',
  array (
    'message' => 'This is a test message',
  )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
`
```

[Api Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed#publish)

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme :)